# Creating a zip for my app in bash script

Tags: xcode, bash, zip, continuous-integration, build-automation

I'm trying to use Xcode 5 bots for my Continuos Integration. I need to create a zip-file of my app-file.

In my scheme under Archive I use this script:

```
LATESTBUILD=$(ls -1rt /Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns | tail -1)
APP="/Library/Server/Xcode/Data/BotRuns/${LATESTBUILD}/output/Archive.xcarchive/Products/Applications/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app"

echo "Zipping .app for ${PRODUCT_NAME}"
/usr/bin/zip -r "${APP}.zip" "${APP}"

echo "Sending to *HockeyApp*"
curl \
-F "status=2" \
-F "notify=0" \
-F "notes=Testing CI" \
-F "notes_type=0" \
-F "ipa=${APP}.zip" \
-H "X-HockeyAppToken: myToken \
https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/myAppID/app_versions/upload
```

This will create a .zip-file. However, not the actual app but the whole folder structure for ${app}.

How can I create a zip-file that only contains the actual app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by stepping in to the directory before zipping it.

```
cd "/tmp/Archive.xcarchive/Products/Applications/"
```

Answer (score 0):

To specify a file parameter with curl, you have to prefix the filename with @. Correct would be:

```
echo "Sending to *HockeyApp*"
curl \
-F "status=2" \
-F "notify=0" \
-F "notes=Testing CI" \
-F "notes_type=0" \
-F "ipa=@${APP}.zip" \
-H "X-HockeyAppToken: myToken \
https://rink.hockeyapp.net/api/2/apps/myAppID/app_versions/upload
```

Comment: I've tried this too. But will try it again just to double check. I've been back and forth with this so many times that I lost count. Will check tonight! Thanks!

Comment: I found out what the problem was. It's not zipping my app, it's zipping the xcarchive file. Do you know why?